# How to convert 1d numpy array to 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy, 2d

I used FeatureClassToNumPyArray. This function creates a numpy array from a FeatureClass (table). 
First parameter specifyied the name of the table. The other parameters are the column-names that are "imported" into the Array.

```
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray("lyr_fixpoints", ('land_type', 'asset_cat', 'name', 'maintenance'), null_value=-999)  
print arr
```

and get the following 1d array:

```
[(5, 0, 380, 3) (1, 4, 369, 3) (5, 0, 421, 2) (0, 7, 425, 1)]
```

Now I want to convert this array into a 2d array of this form, because the 2d array is very suitable for my further operations.

```
[[5 0 380 3] [1 4 369 3] [5 0 421 2] [0 7 425 1]]
```

I tried with reshape but that didn't work. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first array already is 2D! If you're only putting parentheses to show where you want the rows to be split up, here's something:

```
arr.reshape(4, 4)
```

should work. If it doesn't, make sure that arr really is a numpy array. If you're not sure you can use:

```
arr = np.array(arr)
arr.reshape(4, 4)
```

Comment: I tried both of your Statements and I received this error message: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged. I think my first Array is 1d because the output of arr.ndim is 1 and len(arr) is 4.

Comment: It's confusing that arr.ndim is 1.
I tried typing `a = np.array( [(5, 0, 380, 3), (1, 4, 369, 3), (5, 0, 421, 2), (0, 7, 425, 1)])` and a.ndim was 2, as I expected. Also it makes sense that len(arr) would be 4, since its 4 elements are lists, each 4 long.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution to my problem. This code will convert my 1d array (from featureclasstonumpyarray) to a 2d array.

```
arr = np.array([[x for x in y] for y in arr])
```